# Jooq configuration with H2 in memory

Tags: maven, h2, jooq, flyway

I am trying to use flyway, h2 and jooq together.
The problem happens when I try to use h2 in memory.

I did not find an example which uses h2 in memory with flyway to generate the source classes with jooq-codegen-maven plugin.

If my URL looks like this for h2 it works fine

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/h2-flyway-test
```

Comment: Maven plugins tend to be run in different, independent processes for obvious reasons - you don't want one plugin to have any side effects on another one. Hence, you cannot use the H2 in-memory mode, because the database created by Flyway will no longer be available to the jOOQ code generator. This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51328307/521799. Let me know if your issue is different.

Comment: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-flyway/
this one is a good start